# Stopping jquery process

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have one div hidden out of page and one part is visible like:

```css
div{
    left: -100px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

I used jquery to show whole div:

```
$("div").hover(function(){ 
    $("div").animate({left: '0px'});
},function(){
    $("div").animate({left: '-100px'}); 
});
```

When I `hover` over the div and quickly `unhover` over it multiple times, It seems to play the animation the same amount of times I do this. How can I make it stop mid-animation if I stop hovering over the div, and how can I make the animation start only after I have hovered over it for a certain amount of time.

Comment: Why don't you just do `div { width: 150px; height: 50px; transform: translateX(-100px); transition: transform 1s; } div:hover { transform: translateX(0); }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.stop()` to stop the previous animation.

```js
$("div").hover(function() {
  $("div").stop().animate({
    left: '0px'
  }, "slow");
}, function() {
  $("div").stop().animate({
    left: '-100px'
  });
}, "slow");
```

```css
div {
  left: -100px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

If you want it to wait until you've been hovering for a bit before the animation starts, you can use `setTimeout`, and you can cancel the timeout in the unhover function.

```js
var hoverTimer;
$("div").hover(function() {
  hoverTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    $("div").stop().animate({
      left: '0px'
    }, "slow");
  }, 1000);
}, function() {
  clearTimeout(hoverTimer);
  $("div").stop().animate({
    left: '-100px'
  });
}, "slow");
```

```css
div {
  left: -100px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```